# Create a Query in javascript with Datastore

Tags: node.js, angular, datastore

I am having trouble building a datastore query with a filter. I am continually getting a 500 error code.  I have built save, and get modules that work.

Looking for any assistance or ideas in narrowing down my problem.

```
  // moduleAccess.model
  import gstore = require('gstore-node');
  const Schema = gstore.Schema;

  const moduleAccessScheme = new Schema ({
    uuid: {type: 'string', optional: true},
    moduleId: {type: 'string', optional: true},
    accessType: {type: 'string', optional: true},
   active: {type: 'string', optional: true},
   });

  module.exports = gstore.model('ModuleAccess', moduleAccessScheme);
```

--

```
  //moduleAccessController.js
  exports.moduleAccess_queryByUUID = function (req, res, next){
    const uuid = req.params.uuid;
    const query = ModuleAccess.query()
      .filter('uuid', '=', uuid);
    query.run()
      .then((entity) => {
        res.json(entity.plain());
    }).catch(err => res.status(500).json(err));
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out as I couldn't stop mulling over it after I posted the question. The problem was that I was not outputting the array correctly.

The following example now outputs the query lookup properly.

```
exports.moduleAccess_queryByUUID = function (req, res, next){
  const uuid = req.params.uuid;
  const query = datastore.createQuery('ModuleAccess')
    .filter('uuid', '=', uuid);
  datastore.runQuery(query)
    .then((entity) => {
        const modules = entity[0];
        res.json(modules);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        // If there are any validation error on the schema
        // they will be in this error object
        res.status(500).json(err);
    })
};
```